# How to fix UnboundLocalError for unassigned variable that I assigned?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, fractals

I am trying to create a Koch snowflake generator in Python using the Turtle library and recursion. I have a list of strings with hex codes in them and I am using the variable `color` to have the pen change colors in the order of the list. As you can see, I defined `color` outside of the function definition but when I try to run it, I get and UnboundLocalError saying that `color` was referenced before it was assigned. How can I fix the error so my code will run as intended?

Here is some of the code I wrote to generate the Snowflake. `color` is supposed to increase by one every time a line is drawn, so then the next time a line is drawn the color used is a `palette[color % 6]`

```
import turtle

turtle.colormode(255)
palette = ["#ff0f7b","#fd445d","#fc5552","#fa8139","#f98a34","#f89b29"]
color = 0

# Draw a Koch curve
def koch(iteration, length):
    if iteration == 1:
        turtle.forward(length/3)
        turtle.pencolor(palette[color % 6])
        color += 1
    else:
        koch(iteration-1, length/3)
    turtle.left(60)
```

here is the error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hummi\Python Files\koch_snowflake.py", line 49, in <module>
    koch_snowflake(4, 480)
  File "C:\Users\hummi\Python Files\koch_snowflake.py", line 41, in koch_snowflake
    koch(iteration, length)
  File "C:\Users\hummi\Python Files\koch_snowflake.py", line 15, in koch
    koch(iteration-1, length/3)
  File "C:\Users\hummi\Python Files\koch_snowflake.py", line 15, in koch
    koch(iteration-1, length/3)
  File "C:\Users\hummi\Python Files\koch_snowflake.py", line 15, in koch
    koch(iteration-1, length/3)
  File "C:\Users\hummi\Python Files\koch_snowflake.py", line 12, in koch
    turtle.pencolor(palette[color % 6])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'color' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `global color` statement, like this:

```
color = 0

# Draw a Koch curve
def koch(iteration, length):
    global color
    if iteration == 1:
        turtle.forward(length/3)
        turtle.pencolor(palette[color % 6])
        color += 1
```

Without that addition, modifying the value of `color` makes it a locally scoped variable.  Since in that local scope, it hasn't been assigned to yet, and the increment statement requires a previous value for the variable, you get the error that you are seeing.  Adding the `global color` statement forces the statement to refer to the global `color` value, even though it is modifying the value.  If you were only reading from `color`, the `global color` statement wouldn't be necessary.  A slightly strange Python factoid here.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to *cycle* the colors rather than use a global index and modular arithmetic:

```
import turtle
from itertools import cycle

# palette = cycle(["#ff0f7b", "#fd445d", "#fc5552", "#fa8139", "#f98a34", "#f89b29"])
palette = cycle(['#ff0000', '#000000', '#00ffff', '#0000ff', '#00ff00'])

# Draw a Koch curve
def koch(iteration, length):

    if iteration == 1:
        turtle.pencolor(next(palette))
        turtle.forward(length)
    else:
        koch(iteration-1, length/3)
        turtle.left(60)
        koch(iteration-1, length/3)
        turtle.right(120)
        koch(iteration-1, length/3)
        turtle.left(60)
        koch(iteration-1, length/3)

koch(4, 300)

turtle.done()
```

Pallette changed to make color changes more obvious:

[image]